# Object Oriented Programming in JavaScript: how do I call functions from other files?

Tags: javascript, function, oop

I have an app.js and another Highlight.js file.

In Highlight.js I have the following code:

```
export default class Highlights {
function foo() { alert(1) };
}
```

and in app.js I try to call the function foo as follows:

```
import highlight from './custom/HighlightingObjects.js';
highlight.foo();
```

But already at compling this via webpack I get an error message, that there is an unexpected token at:

```
function foo() { alert(1) };
```

How can I handle this?

Comment: **1.** That's not how you define methods inside a class, hence the error

Comment: **3.** `foo`, when fixed, will be a method, so you can't call it like that, you should instantiate the class first like so: `let instance = new Highlights();` then use `foo` like so: `instance.foo();`

Comment: **4.** You mentioned that the file containg the class is called _Highlight.js_, so why are you importing from `'./custom/HighlightingObjects.js'`, please verify the path is correct

Comment: @ibrahimmahrir If you're gonna answer a question please just post it as an answer and not as a comment.

Answer (score 1):

foo is method of class.
Instead

```
export default class Highlights {
  function foo() { alert(1) };
}
```

you need write

```
export default class Highlights {
  foo() { alert(1) };
}
```

Comment: You got one, two to go (the import is not correct and the way he is using `foo` is also not correct).

Comment: Import is correct because 'export default'. In import name does not matter.

Comment: Also, OP  wants to use the the method of the class like a static one, not a normal one.